# Modify MySQL statement to allow update

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can this be modified with an update statement? Want to update the field "email" in the "mdl_user" table with a value of "users@domain.com" with all records that are returned by this statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS userid, c.id AS courseid
FROM mdl_user u
    JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = u.id
    JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
    JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
    JOIN mdl_context ct ON ct.id = ra.contextid
        AND ct.contextlevel =50
    JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = ct.instanceid
        AND e.courseid = c.id
    JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid
        AND r.shortname =  'student'
WHERE e.status =0
AND u.suspended =0
AND u.deleted =0
AND ue.status =0
AND courseid =1538
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the `email` column in the `mdl_users` table?

Comment: Sorry I corrected it to "mdl_user " but yes update "email" column in the table "mdl_user"

Comment: I would not amend this, instead `UPDATE mdl_user SET email = 'users@domain.com' WHERE mdl_user.id = The id you want to update`

Comment: I don't know the user that I am updating until this statement is run, I need to be able to query the users then update them. Ideally in one statement. Multiple users be returned. I want to be able to update multiple users with a default email address that I would add to their record

Comment: @jmadd are you updating all users (From the query) to `'users@domain.com'`?

Comment: `UPDATE mdl_user SET email = 'user@domain.com' WHERE mdl_user IN (` << your sql stuff, only selecting u.id >> )

Comment: Yes, all users returned by this query. Sounds counterintuitive but that is what's needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will update all the selected users:

```
UPDATE mdl_user 
JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS userid, c.id AS courseid
FROM mdl_user u
    JOIN mdl_user_enrolments ue ON ue.userid = u.id
    JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
    JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = u.id
    JOIN mdl_context ct ON ct.id = ra.contextid
        AND ct.contextlevel =50
    JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = ct.instanceid
        AND e.courseid = c.id
    JOIN mdl_role r ON r.id = ra.roleid
        AND r.shortname =  'student'
WHERE e.status =0
AND u.suspended =0
AND u.deleted =0
AND ue.status =0
AND courseid =1538
) AS a
ON a.userid = mdl_user.id
SET email = 'users@domain.com'
```